# A small puzzle of Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

There are 2 tables. One is `User`(`id`, `name`, `email`) and the other is `Student`(`id`, `who_id`).

I wanna Use this way:

```
Student.find(id).name, Student.find(id).email
```

rather than:

```
User.find(student.who_id).name, User.find(student.who_id).email
```

to get data.

How should I do?

btw, I cannot change `who_id` to `user_id` for any reason.

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: Give the whole context of such usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `name` and `email` methods in your Student model, like so:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: :User, foreign_key: 'who_id'

  def name
    user.name
  end

  def email
    user.email
  end
end
```

You could also use Rail's delegate method to do the same thing in less code:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: :User, foreign_key: 'who_id'
  delegate :name, to: :user
  delegate :email, to: :user
end
```

And once you ge tthat working, rather than `Student.find(id).name, Student.find(id).email` (which will fetch the data from the database twice) you should instead do this:

```
student = Student.find(id) #single call to the database
# get the properties from the previous database call
student.name 
student.email
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good method, but I am thinking whether we can create bidirectional models connecting, so that `student.id` will auto delete when `user.id` is destroyed. That is add `dependent: :destroy`. Can we ? Thanks!

Comment: I think this question covers that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939799/has-one-has-many-with-dependent-destroy-but-using-a-different-name-for-the-key